# Timeout Function

Tags: c, linux

I want to make a code in which Name of User will be asked to input, but in a time limit of 15 seconds. If user cross the limit & failed to input a name(or any string), then code will be terminated & "Time Out" Massage will be display otherwise Name should be saved & "Thanks" massage will be display. I had try like this but it's wrong & not working. Please give me a solution for this.. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int timeout ( int seconds )
{
    clock_t endwait;
    endwait = clock () + seconds * CLOCKS_PER_SEC ;
    while (clock() < endwait) {}

    return  1;
}

int main ()
{
    char name[20];
    printf("Enter Username: (in 15 seconds)\n");
    printf("Time start now!!!\n");

    scanf("%s",name);
    if( timeout(5) == 1 ){
        printf("Time Out\n");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Thnaks\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: suggest using: `getitimer()` and `setitimer()` (probably only the `setitimer()` function will be needed. Suggest reading the MAN page for `setitimer()`

Comment: Suggest using the `select()` function, with the last parameter being a `struct timeval` with the contents being 15 seconds

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Probably this dummy program might help you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define WAIT 3

int main ()
{
    char            name[20] = {0}; // in case of single character input
    fd_set          input_set;
    struct timeval  timeout;
    int             ready_for_reading = 0;
    int             read_bytes = 0;
    
    /* Empty the FD Set */
    FD_ZERO(&input_set );
    /* Listen to the input descriptor */
    FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &input_set);

    /* Waiting for some seconds */
    timeout.tv_sec = WAIT;    // WAIT seconds
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;    // 0 milliseconds

    /* Invitation for the user to write something */
    printf("Enter Username: (in %d seconds)\n", WAIT);
    printf("Time start now!!!\n");

    /* Listening for input stream for any activity */
    ready_for_reading = select(1, &input_set, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
    /* Here, first parameter is number of FDs in the set, 
     * second is our FD set for reading,
     * third is the FD set in which any write activity needs to updated,
     * which is not required in this case. 
     * Fourth is timeout
     */

    if (ready_for_reading == -1) {
        /* Some error has occured in input */
        printf("Unable to read your input\n");
        return -1;
    } 

    if (ready_for_reading) {
        read_bytes = read(0, name, 19);
        if(name[read_bytes-1]=='\n'){
        --read_bytes;
        name[read_bytes]='\0';
        }
        if(read_bytes==0){
            printf("You just hit enter\n");
        } else {
            printf("Read, %d bytes from input : %s \n", read_bytes, name);
        }
    } else {
        printf(" %d Seconds are over - no data input \n", WAIT);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Update:

This is now tested code.**

Also, I have taken hints from man for `select`. This manual already contains a code snippet which is being used to read from the terminal and timeout in 5 seconds in case of no activity.

Just a brief explanation in case the code is not well written enough:

1. We add the input stream (`fd = 1`) to the FD set.
2. We initiate `select` call to listen to this FD set created for
   any activity.
3. In case any activity occurs within the `timeout` period, that is
   read through the `read` call.
4. In case there was no activity, timeout occurs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: By the way, your scanf is not working because it is a blocking read call over the input stream.

Comment: Thanks a lot Shrey. Realy this code is very useful for me. Because I got many examples for select() from internet but those were very complex. This code is very easy to understand & make my work. Thanks 4 your help.

Comment: Shrey, I observe that if I remove \n from both of printf statement then it first take read() function and then print massage of printf() statement. what should be the reason for that??

Comment: read() function also gives some garbage characters in output.

Comment: @Heet, read is returning garbage because there is no \0 line endings for what is being printed. Thus, printf of read would try and write all of the 19 characters even if they don't hold the input characters.

Comment: @Heet As for the previous comment, regarding the read before printf, that is because of line buffering. \n would force the output on terminal (as far as I can say). Probably, using a flush like call (before read) would assure that everything is on screen before read is executed.

Comment: No need for flush(), printf is buffered and a mere new-line is enough to flush that buffer to output stream.

Comment: `int select(int nfds, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds,
                  fd_set *exceptfds, struct timeval *timeout);` I forgot to edit the meaning and numbering of parameters for select()

Answer (score 4):

`scanf()` is not the best function to get an input in a limited time frame.

Instead I would build a specific input function around `select()` (for managing timeout) and `read()` (for getting input) system calls.

Comment: thanks mouviciel, Can you please give me syntax of select(), with a sample Example?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you have to think about, is that you have a single thread of execution in your program. As such, the `timeout` function will only be called when the `scanf` function will be terminated. This is not what you want.

One way to do this task, is to use the `select` function. It waits for a potentially limited amount of time (your timeout) for availability of input on some file descriptors (`stdin` for you).