# How to loop select() to poll for data ad infinitum

Tags: c, select, loops, pool, infinite

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main ()
{
char            name[20];
fd_set          input_set;
struct timeval  timeout;
int             ready_for_reading = 0;
int             read_bytes = 0;

/* Empty the FD Set */
FD_ZERO(&input_set );
/* Listen to the input descriptor */
FD_SET(0, &input_set);

/* Waiting for some seconds */
timeout.tv_sec = 10;    // 10 seconds
timeout.tv_usec = 0;    // 0 milliseconds

/* Invitation for the user to write something */
printf("Enter Username: (in 15 seconds)\n");
printf("Time start now!!!\n");

/* Listening for input stream for any activity */
ready_for_reading = select(1, &input_set, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
/* Here, first parameter is value of the socket descriptor + 1 (STDIN descriptor is 0, so  
 * 0 +1 = 1)  
 * in the set, second is our FD set for reading,
 * third is the FD set in which any write activity needs to updated, which is not required
 * in this case. Fourth is timeout
 */

if (ready_for_reading == -1) {
    /* Some error has occured in input */
    printf("Unable to read your input\n");
    return -1;
} else {
    if (ready_for_reading) {
        read_bytes = read(0, name, 19);
        printf("Read, %d bytes from input : %s \n", read_bytes, name);
    } else {
        printf(" 10 Seconds are over - no data input \n");
    }
}

return 0;
```

}

How to do the same, but not just once, but in infinite loop which breaks after encountering 'quit' string (for example). Every way I tried - failed. 
So if no data has been inputed after 10 seconds program just prints "10 secs are over - no data input" and then starts waiting again. Same after input - just begins again and behave the same every time in infinite loop.
Am little desperate already, please - help.
Thanks.

Comment: Put everything in a `while(!strcmp(name, "quit"))` loop or something? :-)

Comment: "Here, first parameter is number of FDs in the set" **no**. It must be the highest FD number plus one. Please go recheck the man page.

Comment: The example at the bottom of http://linux.die.net/man/2/select_tut is exactly what you want.

Comment: @EitanT try to do this with while(1) and U will understand my question ;)

Comment: @user471548 Did you try to enclose the FD_ZERO and FD_SET in the loop as well?

Comment: @Mat yes i know, didnt notice, i copypasted the code from another topic. Fixed.

Comment: @EitanT no. and have no idea how to do this. Can You please provide a code snippet ?

Comment: @user471548, I've outlined the general idea for you in my answer. See if it works for you...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't really see the problem here. Basically just put everything you want in the loop, and let it run. Did you try this?

```
int main ()
{
   /* Declarations and stuff */
   /* ... */

   /* The loop */
   int break_condition = 0;
   while (!break_condition)
   {
       /* Selection */
       FD_ZERO(&input_set );   /* Empty the FD Set */
       FD_SET(0, &input_set);  /* Listen to the input descriptor */
       ready_for_reading = select(1, &input_set, NULL, NULL, &timeout);

       /* Selection handling */
       if (ready_for_reading)
       {
          /* Do something clever with the input */
       }
       else
       {
          /* Handle the error */
       }

       /* Test the breaking condition */
       break_condition = some_calculation();
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Note that you have to have keep resetting the selection inside the loop so that it will respond again in the next iteration.

Comment: Thank You all very much. Solved at last ! :)))
The problem was that I initialized selection arguments only once, and than use them multiple times, while  I should initialize them each time I use select. Really thank You very much. !!!! Greetings

Answer (score 0):

The select() function can be told to block indefinitely by setting *timeout* to NULL. See select(2) man page:

> *timeout* is an upper bound on the amount of time elapsed before **select**() returns. If  both  fields  of  the  *timeval*  stucture  are zero, then **select**() returns immediately.  (This is useful for polling.)  If  *timeout* is NULL (no timeout), **select**() can block indefinitely.

So what you want is:

```
...
ready_for_reading = select(1, &input_set, NULL, NULL, NULL);
...
```