# Exits the loop after a certain amount of time if there's no input

Tags: c

I'm just wondering whether is it possible and how do I implement this feature, where we exit from the loop if there's no input from the user. For example, I want to exit the loop if the user does not input anything after 1 minute. Here's my C code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    time_t end = time(0) + 60;
    printf("Enter a number : ");

    while (time(0) < end)
    {
        if((scanf("%d", &x)) != EOF || (getchar() != '\n'))
        {
            time_t end2 = time(0) + 60;
            while(time(0) < end2);
            main();
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d", x);
            main();
        }
    }
    main();
}
```

Comment: What's with all the recursion?

Comment: Try to avoid using conio.h library, because it's not an standard library of C and it only works in Borland C compiler, and most of those conio.h functions are inside other standard libraries.

Comment: Here some useful references: (1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226603/timeout-function  (2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917881/how-to-implement-a-timeout-in-read-function-call

Comment: Standard C has nothing useful in this department. You need to use platform-specific APIs. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57615/how-to-add-a-timeout-to-console-readline) is a nice Windows-oriented discussion, it uses C# but it shouldn't be too hard to do the same in any language.

Comment: It would be useful to know what compiler are you using and on what platform (linux, win, ..)

Answer (score 2):

Use `select()` function to set a timeout for your scanf

The following code is an example of how use it.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    fd_set          set;
    struct          timeval timeout = {0};

    FD_ZERO(&set);


   while(1)
   {
        timeout.tv_sec = 30;
        FD_SET(fileno( stdin ), &set);
        printf ("enter a number:");
        fflush (stdout);
        if (select(FD_SETSIZE, &set, NULL, NULL, &timeout))
        {

           scanf("%d", &x);
           printf("The number you put is %d\r\n",x);

        }
        else
        {
                printf("\r\nTimeout: Stop reading\r\n");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I couldn't compile your code. I've gotten these errors:

[Error] C:\Users\SilverRhythm\Documents\C-Free\Temp\Untitled5.cpp:8: error: `fd_set' was not declared in this scope
[Error] C:\Users\SilverRhythm\Documents\C-Free\Temp\Untitled5.cpp:8: error: expected `;' before "set"
[Error] C:\Users\SilverRhythm\Documents\C-Free\Temp\Untitled5.cpp:11: error: `set' was not declared in this scope
[Error] C:\Users\SilverRhythm\Documents\C-Free\Temp\Untitled5.cpp:11: error: `FD_ZERO' was not declared in this scope

Comment: and these as well :

[Error] C:\Users\SilverRhythm\Documents\C-Free\Temp\Untitled5.cpp:17: error: `FD_SET' was not declared in this scope
[Error] C:\Users\SilverRhythm\Documents\C-Free\Temp\Untitled5.cpp:20: error: `FD_SETSIZE' was not declared in this scope
[Error] C:\Users\SilverRhythm\Documents\C-Free\Temp\Untitled5.cpp:20: error: `select' was not declared in this scope

Comment: I'm new to 'fd_set', so I'm not sure to repair it. It's my first time using these functions.

Comment: I build my source code on linux and it works. check in your source code that you include `#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>`

Comment: are you using visual studio ?

Comment: check if one of the followinf=g include could solve your problem maybe one of them contains select I did not check it  `#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <string.h>

#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/types.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>`

Comment: Awesome. I've got it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Although the time_t structure returned by time() is most likely a number of seconds, you should not be performing maths on it.  Instead use difftime()

```
double difftime ( time_t time2, time_t time1 );
```

Calculates the difference in seconds between time1 and time2.

You do not need to call `main()` from within `main()` and I'm not sure why you would think that is a good idea.

Also, `getchar()` will wait for a key to be pressed, so it won't be counting time in the background.

Answer (score 0):

This task is usually done using threads. In one thread `getchar` is called which blocks the thread execution, another thread does `sleep()` and then kills the first thread.

Another way to do this is to use non-blocking `read()` from the standard input using `pselect (2)`, but it's more tricky and does not suit small applications well.

Though a solution with `pthreads` in unix-style is quite verbose:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct read_int {
    int success;
    int value;
    struct timespec timeout;
};

void* read_thread(void *arg) {
    struct read_int *s = arg;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &s->value);
    s->success = 1;
    return NULL;
}

#define CHECK_RET(ret, func) \
    if (ret) { fprintf(stderr, func"() == %d\n", ret); return ret; }

int main() {
    pthread_t rthr;
    pthread_attr_t thr_attr;

    struct read_int s = { 0 };
    int ret;

    ret = clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &s.timeout);
    if (ret == -1) { fprintf(stderr, "clock_gettime() == %d\n", ret);  return ret; }

    s.timeout.tv_sec += 5;

    ret = pthread_attr_init(&thr_attr);
    CHECK_RET(ret, "pthread_attr_init");

    ret = pthread_create(&rthr, &thr_attr, read_thread, &s);
    CHECK_RET(ret, "pthread_create");

    ret = pthread_attr_destroy(&thr_attr);
    CHECK_RET(ret, "pthread_attr_destroy");

    pthread_timedjoin_np(rthr, NULL, &s.timeout);

    if (s.success) {
        printf("\ngot value %d\n", s.value);
    } else {
        pthread_cancel(rthr);
        printf("\nTimed out, exiting...\n\n");
    }
}
```