# How to continue if no input is entered by user

Tags: c, input

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    ...
    input[i] = getch();
    delay(800);
}
```

is there a way that the program will continue even
if no key was entered?

(I'm trying to make Guitar Hero,that continue if the color not typed)

Comment: What is the platform (OS and compiler) you are targetting for?

Comment: You probably need to do it in 2 threads: one to input and the other to timing.  When the time finishes, kill off the input thread.

Comment: The OS is most likely to be windows, and the compiler is probably boorland or something like that...(In visual studio, it's `_getch()` not `getch()`. `getch()` is not standard `C`

Comment: You can use a timeout as in this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226603/timeout-function

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MSVC you can do it like this. You can enter keys as fast as you like, so you don't have to guess the timing, but each key must be within 800ms of the previous.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define LENGTH  10
#define TIMEOUT (0.8 * CLOCKS_PER_SEC)

int main (void)
{
    int i;
    int keys[LENGTH] = {0};
    clock_t target;
    for (i=0; i<LENGTH; i++) {
        target = clock() + (clock_t)TIMEOUT;
        while(clock() < target) {
            if (_kbhit()) {
                keys[i] = _getch();
                break;
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n", keys[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program output, showing where I typed 4 keys within time, and where I did not:

```
0
0
49
0
50
51
52
0
0
0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    ...
    if(_kbhit())
        input[i] = getch();
    delay(800);
}
```

This should work if you have the _kbhit/kbhit function on the target platform.

Comment: The delay should be 80 if you're going round 10 times: then it will pop out of the loop after 800ms.  I am assuming the parameter for delay is in ms.

Comment: @cup I thought it was clear from the question that it is 800 ms per key. I can't see anyone easily pressing 10 correct keys in less than a second.

Answer (score 1):

Im using Gcc compiler, run in the cmd(Windows 10)
will _kbhit() work?
have a nice week.
Merry Chrismes